# Why does the Simics Registers window show 32 bit registers when the disassembly view shows code is running 64-bit?

Tags: simics

I'm on the 2021.24 Simics and I just started the sim w/ "run-command-file targets\qsp-x86\firststeps.simics", and then run, and then stop. When I look at the CPU registers window I see the below with 32 bit registers instead of 64 bit. Is this a bug? Shouldn't the registers view show the 64 bit registers when executing 64 bit code? Or at least have a UI option to force that to be the case?

[image: 32 bit registers]

Answer (score 0):

Please see for example https://cs.brown.edu/courses/cs033/docs/guides/x64_cheatsheet.pdf that explains the view you see. Quote: "Additionally, the lower bytes of some of these
registers may be accessed independently as 32-, 16- or 8-bit registers. The register names are
as follows: ..." And there you see that the **e..** registers are indeed 32-bit registers. Though they are part of the larger **r..** registers when used in 64-bit architectures.

Comment: I'm aware that the E forms are the 32-bit versions of the 64-bit R forms. What I'm asking is why the Registers window is showing the 32 bit forms when it's clearly executing 64-bit code, and if there's any way to change it to show the 64-bit forms (I haven't been able to find such a way)

Comment: I cannot answer that question, to be honest. I may be that in quite some time we have not done much to the old Winsome UI.

Comment: OK, well at a minimum I think it's probably at least worth a bug ticket to track the fact that the registers window isn't showing full register state. Thank you